# PHP fetch data from mysql and show accordingly

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with products and categories tables. I have managed to show the product category and It's related products. And It's currently looks like following.

[image]

But I need this to be done like

```
Category B
   Product 1

Category A
   Product 2
   Product 3
   Product 4
   Product 5
```

Following is my query

```
<?php                        
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
{  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
?>  
<h1><?php echo $row["name"];?></h1>
<p><?php echo $row["prod_desc"];?></p>
<a href=""><?php echo $row["prod_name"]; ?></a>
<?php echo $row["quantity"]; ?>
<?php echo $row["buy_price"]; ?>
<?php  
}  
}  
?>
```

Comment: So you just need to rearrange the array

Comment: Yes, you're right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rearrange array first then try to use it for showing data

```
<?php
    $final_array = [];
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  {  
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $final_array[$row["name"]][] = ['prod_desc'=>$row["prod_desc"],'prod_name'=>$row["prod_name"],'quantity'=>$row["quantity"],'price'=>$row["buy_price"]];
        }
?>
        <?php foreach($final_array as $key=>$val){?>  
            <h1><?php echo $key;?></h1>
            <?php foreach($val as $v){?>
                <p><?php echo $v["prod_desc"];?></p>
                <a href=""><?php echo $v["prod_name"]; ?></a>
                <?php echo $row["quantity"]; ?>
                <?php echo $row["buy_price"]."<br><br>"; ?>
            <?php  } ?>
        <?php   } ?>
    <?php }?>
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. Thank you very much

Comment: @MahishanRanasinghe  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

Try to store last used category and check if it changed:

```html
<?php                        
$category='';
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
{  
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
 {  
  if($category!=$row["name"]) {
  ?>  
  <h1><?php echo $row["name"];?></h1>
  ?>
  }
  $category=$row["name"];
  <?php
  <p><?php echo $row["prod_desc"];?></p>
  <a href=""><?php echo $row["prod_name"]; ?></a>
  <?php echo $row["quantity"]; ?>
  <?php echo $row["buy_price"]; ?>
  <?php  
  }  
}  
?>
```

Remember to sort output data by category in SQL query